# Changing the EF connection string gives - Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, connection-string

For the past few hours I've been looking into this problem, found many similar topics but none of them seems to help.

I have a `C#` application that uses the `Entity Framework 5` and I have a `.edmx` data model that works fine when using the connection string from the app config file.

Now I would like to change the connection string during runtime, but it throws an exception that says:

> Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

Here is the code that I have:

```
private string GetNewConnectionString(string server, string database, string username, string password)
{
    var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
        DataSource = server,
        InitialCatalog = database,
        UserID = username,
        Password = password,
        IntegratedSecurity = true,
        MultipleActiveResultSets = true
    };

    var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
        Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
        ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString(),
        Metadata = "res://*/MyTestModel.MyTestModel.csdl|res://*/MyTestModel.MyTestModel.ssdl|res://*/MyTestModel.MyTestModel.msl"
    };

    return entityBuilder.ToString();
}

public void insertInDB()
{
    var newConnectionString = GetNewConnectionString(server, database, username, password);
    //newConnectionString = newConnectionString .Replace("\"", "&quot;"); // doesn't help
    //newConnectionString = newConnectionString .Replace("\"", "'"); // doesn't help either

     using (var context = new MyTestModel.MyEntities(newConnectionString)) // it crashes here
     {

     }
 }
```

The metadata should be correct, because I have copied it from the app config file, also if I copy the value of `newConnectionString` to the app config and use it, it works fine if I replace the quotations with `&quot;`.

This is the value of `newConnectionString` (i've only replaced the credentials with some dummy credentials):

> metadata=res://*/MyTestModel.MyTestModel.csdl|res://*/MyTestModel.MyTestModel.ssdl|res://*/MyTestModel.MyTestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
>   connection string="Data Source=myServer;Initial
>   Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=True;User
>   ID=myDbUser;Password=myDbUserPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

I cannot see what is wrong with it, can anybody spot something?

Comment: You are using the wrong provider. If you want that connection to work use *System.Data.EntityClient* instead of System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Another person had the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25041876/609176

Comment: @rene I tried that but then it gives another exception - `The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.`

Comment: @DavidSpence I saw this post, please check my comment above.

Comment: Just to mention that I have the Entity framework 5.0 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer: [Entity Framework change connection at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20254520/1699611) solves the problem

I cannot understand what the problem with my code was, but it works fine with the extension method from the link.