# Program returns "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devextreme

First of all I've read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183777/keyword-not-supported-metadata) and I'm having a different issue.

I'm using DevExtreme and upon debugging I'm getting an error whilst trying to execute this code:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

It says

> "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."

However my the providerName of my connectionString (in the web.config file) is "System.Data.EntityClient" as advised multiple times in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183777/keyword-not-supported-metadata).

My connectionString looks like this:

```
<add name="CCBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ContosoModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ContosoModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ContosoModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\CCB.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;connect timeout=30;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I'm passing this value over like this:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CCBEntities %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CcbTeam]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How can I remove this error?

Comment: Why not just adding supplementary connection string using `SqlClient` provider with different key name? You can copy the section inside `provider connection string`, format it and set `SqlDataSource`'s `ConnectionString` property to a new key name.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto So I've copied the connectionString and renamed providerName from `System.Data.EntityClient` to `System.Data.SqlClient`. I gave it another key name as well. What do you mean with _format it_?

Comment: Remove `metadata`, `application name=EntityFramework` and other EF-related options, also use `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`. Then your setup with new key name should be fine.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto "Keyword not supported: 'provider'." It seems to be having an issue with my connectionString. My connectionString looks like this now: 
`<add name="CCBEntities" connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
         attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\CCB.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;connect timeout=30;&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: The correct one should be this: `<add name="CCBEntities" connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\CCB.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;connect timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`. The EF-related properties should be removed.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Listen man, it works. Thanks a lot. I know it's my first time working with connection strings so I don't really know the difference of the properties yet.