# How can I fix "Keyword not suported: metadata" when opening a SQL Connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to connect to a database, but it seems like my connection is not going through. I am using C# MVC for the webpage I'm creating. How can I fix the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.'.

The error is occuring on the line `using (Sqlconnection con = new Sqlconnection(conStr))`. What am I doing wrong on this line and is this how you call your SQL query in C# MVC?

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Training_DatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString;
List<FisYear> YerFis = new List<FisYear>();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[FiscalYear]", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
        FisYear fy = new FisYear();
        fy.FisDate = rdr["ST_FI"].ToString();
        YerFis.Add(fy);
    }

    SelectList list = new SelectList(YerFis, "ST_FI", "FisDate");
    ViewBag.DropdownList = list;
}
```

Comment: its seems your connection string is wrong.Please check connection string

Comment: Or include your connection string in your question, so we can have a look at it

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Training_DatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=cntrra02-sql-rs;initial catalog=Training_Database;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyword Not Supported: Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183777/keyword-not-supported-metadata)

Comment: You could try reading the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly trying to use an [entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/entity-framework) [connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/connection-strings) to open a connection via `new SqlConnection`, which won't work.

If you look in your `web.config` file you'll probably see something similar to:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Training_DatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entity.csdl|res://*.............provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=............." />
</connectionStrings>
```

You could try parsing the connection string by hand to retrieve the bit you actually want, a brief web search suggests that the [`EntityConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder) may be of use to retrieve it programmatically, here's an example of doing that in a console app:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Training_DatabaseEntities"]
                       .ConnectionString;

var entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
var sqlConnectionConnectionString = entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;

Console.WriteLine($"EF Connection String: {connectionString}");
Console.WriteLine($"SqlConnection Connection String: {sqlConnectionConnectionString}");
```

This gives the output (my emphasis):

> EF Connection String: metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=cntrra02-sql-rs;initial catalog=Training_Database;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
>
> SqlConnection Connection String: **data source=cntrra02-sql-rs;initial catalog=Training_Database;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework**

Which shows a connection string that can be passed into a `SqlConnection` instance.

Comment: Am having a problem when it comes to this line,  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[FiscalYear]", con);   it says can't convert system.data.core.entityclient to system.data.sqlclient. how can i fix that.. using (EntityConnection con = new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[FiscalYear]", con);

Comment: the link you provided it gives me a problem of converting entityclient to sqlclient, how can i solve that

Comment: @Madonado, Short answer: You can't mix EntityConnection and SqlConnection. Long answer: You need to use something like the referenced `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` to extract the "plain" connection string  and create a `SQLConnection`. If I can, I'll add an example of this to the answer later.

Comment: @Madonado, example/sample added :)