# how to solve 'Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I'm trying to connect to my database with SQL client but I can't connect.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="RegisterDBEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Register.csdl|res://*/Register.ssdl|res://*/Register.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\RegisterDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Which one are you using, MSSQL or MySql

Comment: check that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183777/keyword-not-supported-metadata

Comment: This is not a "generic" connection string  - it's a very specific **Entity Framework** connection string, for a version of EF that works with a `.edmx` model file -  a rather old version of EF therefore. Is that your problem maybe? You need a "generic" connection string but copied an EF-model-based Entity connection string by accident??